# Redis Cache - Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-cache, redis-cache

I'm using Spring Cache for Redis.  I've 2 methods each returns policyTest object but are invoked with different parameters as shown below.

```
//  @Cacheable(value = "policyTest", key = "#policyNo")
@Cacheable(value = "policyTest")
  public PolicyTest getPolicyByNo(String policyNo) {
    log.info("RedisServiceImpl::getPolicyByNo() fetching TestPolicy from service ...");
    return new PolicyTest(policyNo, "1005", "200555");
  }




 //  @Cacheable(value = "policyTest", key = "#policyNo")    
  @Cacheable(value = "policyTest")
  public PolicyTest getPolicyByCustomerNo(String customerNo) {
    log.info("RedisServiceImpl::getPolicyByCustomerNo() fetching TestPolicy from service ...");
    return new PolicyTest("125", "1005", customerNo);
  }
```

For both methods, specified policyNo as key, but it is failing for getPolicyByCustomerNo(String customerNo) with error `Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?)`
Without any key specified, the cache has dulicate PolicyTest object that are returned from both methods.

What I want is

1. Have a single copy of customer in the cache, irresective of the input.  But now the same object are cached twice
2. want to specify @Cacheable with key, but it throws error - Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use key ="#p0"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).